# Nested FOL formulae

Tags: first-order-logic

Is there a GENERAL FOL formulae to represent nested expression?

Example:

A(x) ∧ B(x) ∧ (C(x) ∨ D(x)  ∨ ( ¬ E(x) ∧ F(x) )  ∨ G(x) )  ∧ ¬ H(x)

Comment: As Sum Of Product?

Comment: No no I'm interesting in the general formulae about the structure of the nesting.

Comment: What do you mean by a general formula?  You example is missing connectives between $B(x)$ and $(C(x)$ and again after $D(x)$.  The parentheses are also mismatched.  How would you like this to be represented?

Comment: I've just fixed the errors. Anyway, I don't know how to represent the nesting in FOL. In that example I have nested 2 times, but I can also do that N times. Is there a general formulae to represent those situations?

Comment: Again: What do you mean by a general formula? What is it that you want this general formula to satisfy exactly? Or do you want a name for a class of formulas which are nested N times?